# Angular material tabs initial active tab

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, angular-material-6

I am having an issue where when first heading to a URL the Angular Material tabs component doesn't seem to highlight the active tab. It does start highlighting the tab after I press one of them (apart from the one I was initially on).

For example, I have the following routes in my module:

```
const routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/account/overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '',  component: AccountComponent, children: [
            { path: 'overview', component: AccountOverviewComponent },
            { path: 'profiles', component: AccountProfilesComponent },
            { path: 'notifications', component: AccountNotificationsComponent },
            { path: 'billing', component: AccountBillingComponent },
            { path: 'api', component: AccountApiComponent },
            { path: 'security', component: AccountSecurityComponent }
        ]
    },
];
```

As you can see this will redirect `/account` to `/account/overview` which is one of my tabs specified in my `AccountComponent`:

```
this.navLinks = [
    { label: 'Overview', path: './overview', index: 0 },
    { label: 'Profiles', path: './profiles', index: 1 },
    { label: 'Notifications', path: './notifications', index: 2 },
    { label: 'Security', path: './security', index: 2 },
    { label: 'Billing', path: './billing', index: 4 },
    { label: 'API', path: './api', index: 5 },
];
```

and rendered to the page like so:

```
<a mat-tab-link
    *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
    [routerLink]="link.path"
    routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [active]="rla.isActive">

    {{ link.label }}
</a>
```

It just seems to be a issue when I try to access any of the tabs directly. Otherwise it seems to work fine when clicking around. Any ideas?

Comment: Where you able to figured out what the issue was? I've looked at some of the code examples on the [Angular Material site](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples), but I haven't been able to determine why. Is it a missing module?